# Throw error during download in www class Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day guys how can I throw an error during `WWW.isDone(){}` in Unity . I can't seem to find any reference about that .

I'm doing something like this

```
tring path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "datacenter.json");

        string jsonString = null;

        if (path.Contains(":\\") || path.Contains(":/"))
        {
            WWW www = new WWW(path);

            while (!www.isDone) { }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
            {
                tzSceneManager.instance.CreateEmergencyPopup("DATACENTER_ERROR", LocalizationManager.GetText(eTextKey.DATACENTER_ERROR), "OK", null, () =>
                {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                    UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#else
                   Application.Quit();
#endif
                });
            }
            else
            {
                jsonString = www.text.Trim();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jsonString = File.ReadAllText(path);
        }

        CheckJSonManager.Instance._DataCenterJson = JsonMapper.ToObject<DataCenterJson>(jsonString);
        DataCenter_BaseURL = CheckJSonManager.Instance._DataCenterJson.dataCenter;
```

I can't try my `CreateEmergencyPopup()` method because i can't make the error . 
I'm sorry for this question .

Comment: You mean something like `Debug.LogError("...");` ?

Comment: @derHugo no . Like to make an error to show this line of code `tzSceneManager.instance.CreateEmergencyPopup("DATACENTER_ERROR", LocalizationManager.GetText(eTextKey.DATACENTER_ERROR), "OK", null, () =>
                {`

Comment: Oh ok I see .. and what exactly is not working? You get anything in the console? Is the code executed at all? And what exactly is `tzSceneManager` and `CreateEmergencyPopup`?

Comment: Ooooh or do you just want a test case? Why not just put another string there like `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("lol"))`? ;)

Comment: @derHugo It is just a testcase .

Comment: Than you can use my comment before and just insert a string that is definitely not NullOrEmpty to make the if case occure